# Why maven-surefire-plugin would run on my integration test

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

It is weird that I see surefire plugin run on my integration test. Anyone know why ?

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ xxxx ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/jzhang/github/project/module-A/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running package.XXXXIT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's natural. You need to tell maven-surefire-plugin to skip execution of your tests ending with *IT.java.

```
<build> 
<plugins> 
   <plugin>          
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.20</version>    
       <configuration>
            <excludes>    
                  <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude> 
            </excludes> 
       </configuration> 
   </plugin>
</plugins>       
</build>
```